# When to use next() and return next() in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, v8

**Scenario**: Consider the following is the part of code from a node web app.

```
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;
    if (id) {
        // do something
    } else {
        next(); //or return next();
    }
});
```

**Issue**: I am checking which one to go with just `next()` or `return next()`. Above sample code works exactly the same for both & did not show any difference in execution.

**Question**: Can some one put light on this, when to use `next()` and when to use `return next()` and some important difference?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Some people always write `return next()` is to ensure that the execution stops after triggering the callback.

If you don't do it, you risk triggering the callback a second time later, which usually has devastating results. Your code is fine as it is, but I would rewrite it as:

```js
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;

    if(!id)
        return next();

    // do something
});
```

It saves me an indentation level, and when I read the code again later, I'm sure there is no way `next` is called twice.

Comment: Would a similar thing be true of `res.redirect('/')` vs. `return res.redirect('/')` in this type of situation? Maybe it's just better to always write return in front of res statements to avoid errors of setting headers after they were sent?

Comment: @AdamD I would like to know that as well.

Comment: @theprogrammer Yes, I think this answer applies the same way to things like `res.redirect` and it would be best practice to use it, unless you have some other server tasks you want to do after redirecting the user.

Answer (score 350):

As @Laurent Perrin's answer:

> If you don't do it, you risk triggering the callback a second time later, which usually has devastating results

I give an example here if you write middleware like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is a middleware')
  next()
  console.log('This is first-half middleware')
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is second middleware')
  next()
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is third middleware')
  next()
})
```

You will find out that the output in console is:

```
This is a middleware
This is second middleware
This is third middleware
This is first-half middleware
```

That is, it runs the code below next() after all middleware function finished.

However, if you use `return next()`, it will jump out the callback immediately and the code below `return next()` in the callback will be unreachable.

Comment: As a beginner to `express` this answer made things clearer to me than the other answers. Thumbs up!

Comment: Would a similar thing be true of `res.redirect('/')` vs. `return res.redirect('/')` in this type of situation? Maybe it's just better to always write `return` in front of `res` statements to avoid errors of setting headers after they were sent?

Comment: Why should I write code after next()? Isn't it obvious that I do nothing after I finished my task in a middleware? @PJCHENder

Comment: @ImranPollob sometimes mistakes happens. When you write a lot of code, ifs/elses/etc. You may forget ```return next()`

Comment: @ImranPollob - There could very well be times where you want your code to *unwrap* (so to speak), and come back to a middleware that was executed earlier. The fact that it will only actually unwrap and reach code positioned after `next()`, if no other middleware's have `return`ed yet, could be exactly what you're looking to do. Special types of logging, caching, or analytics spring to mind as potential use cases, although this should really be used sparingly, as it would quickly become confusing if you're using this technique all over the place.

Answer (score 54):

`next()` is part of [connect middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/57cfee04a759ac81597a2e61add3795064b1c320/index.js#L239). Callbacks for router flow doesn't care if you return anything from your functions, so `return next()` and `next(); return;` is basically the same.

In case you want to stop the flow of functions you can use `next(err)` like the following

```
app.get('/user/:id?', 
    function(req, res, next) { 
        console.log('function one');
        if ( !req.params.id ) 
            next('No ID'); // This will return error
        else   
            next(); // This will continue to function 2
    },
    function(req, res) { 
        console.log('function two'); 
    }
);
```

Pretty much `next()` is used for extending the middleware of your requests.

Comment: Can we send parameter like: `next('No ID')` ?

Comment: `next('No ID')` is actually sending an error, which will break the flow.

Comment: Use next(null, "somevalue");  For tools like async.waterfall it will pass the value to the next function.

For complex series of interactions that are data driven, I usually pass a context object between functions.  That way I can create generic functions that can be shared across multiple end points and control flow via data in the context

Comment: "so return next() and next(); return; is basically the same." - just what I needed to read. thx @drinchev

Comment: I observe the opposite (when firing error): next(error) triggers next middleware, but continues to execute code; return next(error) just relegates execution to the next middleware. next(e) and return next(e) are NOT the same.

Comment: But than I admit that context here is a bit different. But still, if you anticipate (or generate error) several errors in async middleware, you should 'return next(e)'

Comment: Wrong about next().  It can't stop the flow of the function it's in.  The next() function itself will return to the next line.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between next() and return next() is very simple as another programming principle. Some lines of code are explain below:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
       console.log('Calling first middleware');
       next();
       console.log('Calling after the next() function');
    });


    app.use((req, res, next) => {
       console.log('Calling second middleware');
       return next(); // It returns the function block immediately and call next() function so the return next(); and next(); return; are the same
       console.log('After calling return next()');
    });
```

#### Output is

> Calling first middleware
> Calling after the next() function
> Calling second middleware

Comment: Are you sure your output is correct? Doesn't `Calling after the next() function` come after `Calling second middleware`?

Answer (score 4):

```js
import express from "express"
  
const app = express()
// API for the testing of next() 
app.get(
  '/next', function (req,res,next) { 
    console.log('hi there ');
    next();
    console.log('you are still here');
  }
)
  
// API for the testing of return next() 
app.get(
  '/return-next', function (req,res,next) { 
    console.log('hi there');
    return next(); 
    console.log('you are still here');
  }
)
  
app.listen(5000,()=> {
  console.log("App is running on port 5000")
})
```

`next()` in `/**next**` route will call the middlewares and after the middlewares are executed it comes back to where it is called (same like a function call) and executes the rest of the codes

**output**:

```
hi there

you are still here
```

In `/**return-next**` route there is a return in front of `next()` which returns the controller

**output**:

```
hi there
```

if you consider `next()` like a function call you could understand it properly

Answer (score 0):

Rony's example is quite good. However, I believe that the output is:

Calling first middleware
Calling second middleware
Calling after the next() function

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.