# return next() in nodejs confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js

https://github.com/hwz/chirp/blob/master/module-5/completed/routes/api.js

```
function isAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
    // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
    // request and response objects

    //allow all get request methods
    if(req.method === "GET"){
        return next();
    }
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }

    // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
    return res.redirect('/#login');
};
```

Why does the author do `return next()` instead of `next()`? I know `next()` is to let the flow jump to next middleware or function, but why it needs a `return` for `next()` above?

Comment: So `isAuthenticated` returns whatever `next()` returns. This may not be a useful value, mind you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810449/when-to-use-next-and-return-next-in-node-js but it's valid and good question

Comment: In the context of express middle-ware its to halt executing that specific piece of middle-ware should it fall into either of those if statements. Calling `next` tells express 'im done here move on' however without the `return` it could call `next` but then also try and perform a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

It's a convention to prepend a `return` to exit the function. The alternative would be to use `if-else if-else` instead of just `if`. In this case you just want to exit the function and step further on your middleware chain.

You'll see this pattern quite often. For example, this is pretty common:

```
someFunction(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    console.log(result);
});
```

It's less nesting and reads easier to most poeple compared to this:

```
someFunction(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

The first pattern also keeps you from accidentally calling `next()` twice or even more times in case you have some error in your `if-else`-logic. **And that's exactly what's not supposed to happen with `next()` in that case you posted.** It could call `next()` and still cause the redirect in any case.

Comment: is this answering the question? I know what next() does but why return next(), that's my question

Comment: That's exactly what I am explaining in my answer, yes. It's just to exit the method at that point to avoid further calls. It's a pattern. It has nothing to do with `next()` really. It's mostly because the nature of _callback hell_.