# How can I make a callback that requires info of its child function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, haraka

I am working in a project that uses Node.js for a [Haraka](https://github.com/haraka/Haraka) (an smtp server) plugin.

This is Node.JS and I have a little problem whith callbacks. I haven't been able to convert this particular code to use a callback.

So, this is the code that I have:

```
exports.hook_data = function (next, connection) {
    connection.transaction.add_body_filter('', function (content_type, encoding, body_buffer) {
        var header = connection.transaction.header.get("header");
        if (header == null || header == undefined || header == '') return body_buffer;

        var url = 'https://server.com/api?header=' + header ;
        var request = require('request');
        request.get({ uri: url },
          function (err, resp, body) {
              var resultFromServer = JSON.parse(body);
              return ChangeBuffer(content_type, encoding, body_buffer, resultFromServer);
          }
        );
    });
    return next();
}
```

This code does not work because It doesn't wait the callback of the Request to continue. I need to finish the request before `next()`;

And these are the requirements:

1. At the end of `exports.hook_data` is mandatory to return `next()`. But it only have to return it after the request.
2. I need to return a `Buffer` in `add_body_filter` but I need to create the buffer with information getted from a server.
3. To make the Get Request I need to use a parameter (`header`) that I only have inside `add_body_filter`.

So the issue is that I can not make the request before `add_body_filter` and put the result inside a callback because the parameter that I need to make the request are only inside `add_body_filter`.

Any advice please?

Comment: You can't use an async function in Javascript, but demand that it behave synchronously.  That is simply NOT possible.  If you have an async operation, then you MUST code to use it asynchronously.  That means returning results in a promise or via a callback, NOT via the return value from the function because the function will return BEFORE the async operation is even complete.  You would probably benefit from reading this [How to return response from asynchronous operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).

Comment: Can you pass a callback to `ChangeBuffer`?

Comment: And where do you use `body_buffer` (see the line #4) and the result of `ChangeBuffer(content_type, encoding, body_buffer, resultFromServer)` (see the line #11) which you return? I guess nowhere, right?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin the return of `add_body_filter` is a buffer, this buffer contains the body of an email. I dont use it directly, the server uses it when processing an email.

I write ChangeBuffer so I can pass a callback If needed.

Comment: Can you use Async.js or Promises to control the flow? Otherwise, you'll just end up with a really hacky solution to be honest.

Comment: @Quy Are there any counterproductive things of using something like That or some kind of syncronouz request? It will impact in the scalability of the solution in some way? I have heard that you should always be asynchronous  in Node.js

Comment: @RicardoPolo A lot of things are async, but in order for this to work you need to call the async functions in order to get your desired behavior. All the async calls you make from this function will still get queued in the event loop and get called eventually with all the other IO tasks. Node will take care of that for you. Your current thread, I can't speak much about since I don't know the architecture of your app or what you're doing. For an HTTP server using express, it'll handle the threading on all the requests so you never really have to worry about it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell us how `hook_data` function is called? How the caller attempts to use its results?

Comment: @RicardoPolo please, add an example in your question of how you suppose to use `hook_data` function. Is it intended to create a queue of data readers that is filled with loop?

Comment: better look at some libs like https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: add_body_filter is written by you or its library function? I think you need to modify add_body_filter function.

Comment: var header = connection.transaction.header.get("header"); Why this code would work only inside add_body_filter.

Comment: @rishabhdev is of the add_body_filter.  Only works inside because the body filters runs at the end of the SMTP transmision, if you run outside it you get a empty header because it has not been transmited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are willing to use synchronous, blocking functions, it is impossible to satisfy the requirements you have numbered.

I would examine reasons underlying each requirement and see if you accomplish your goals in a different way.

On face value, looking at just the code you have there, I would look for a way to alter the contract of `exports.hook_data` so that you're able to call `next()` from inside the `request.get` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Use Async.js or Promises.

Async implementation:

```
exports.hook_data = function (next, connection) {
  async.waterfall([
    function( done ) {
      connection.transaction.add_body_filter('', function( content_type, encoding, body_buffer ) {
        var header = connection.transaction.header.get("header");
        if ( header == null || header == undefined || header == '' ) {
          done(null, body_buffer);
        }
        done(null, header);
      });
    },
    function( header, done ) {
      var url = 'https://server.com/api?header=' + header;
      var request = require('request');
      request.get({ uri: url },
        function( err, resp, body ) {
          // do something if there's an error
          var resultFromServer = JSON.parse(body);
          done(null, ChangeBuffer(content_type, encoding, body_buffer, resultFromServer));
        }
      );
    }
  ], function( error, buffer ) {
    // do something if there's error
    next(buffer);
  });
}
```

There's a lot here and I recommend you reading the docs on [async.js#waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback). Essentially it breaks up each async call into it's on function block and waits for it to return before it continues onto the next block.

Again, since these are all async, Node submits these tasks to the IO event loop and it's taken care of there (non-blocking). When this thread is waiting, it'll probably move on to the next request while this request is waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Haraka manual for [Transaction object](https://haraka.github.io/manual/Transaction.html) & [Header object](https://haraka.github.io/manual/Header.html) I don't see there is any dependency of Header on `add_body_filter`. Also your code doesn't show any dependency on `add_body_filter`. So your 3rd requirement looks invalid.

Considering that, I think following pseudocode(as I can't test it) should work for you.

```
exports.hook_data = function (next, connection) {
    var header = connection.transaction.header.get("header");
    if (header == null || header == undefined || header == '') {
        return next();

    var url = 'https://server.com/api?header=' + header ;
    var request = require('request');
    request.get({ uri: url },
        function (err, resp, body) {
            var resultFromServer = JSON.parse(body);
            connection.transaction.add_body_filter('', function (content_type, encoding, body_buffer) {
                return ChangeBuffer(content_type, encoding, body_buffer, resultFromServer);
            });
            next();
        }
    );
}
```

If Haraka manual has failed to highlight the dependency of Header on `add_body_filter` and / or you have discovered it based on your practical experience, then Quy's approach seems to be the way to go.

If you are wondering [when to use next() v/s return next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810449/when-to-use-next-and-return-next-in-node-js)

Comment: sadly you cant use connection.transaction.header.get("header") outside add_body_filter. You can use it in another events but in the Data event it will always return empty values :(

Answer (score 0):

For handling priority of each part of your code I use `Q`, You can use it in few steps:

1. `npm install q`.

   ```
   var request = require('request');
   var Q = require('q');

   exports.hook_data = function () {
      var url, header;
      Q()
      .then(function(){
        connection.transaction.add_body_filter('', function(content_type, encoding, body_buffer) {

         header = connection.transaction.header.get("header");

         if (header == null || header == undefined || header == ''){return body_buffer;}
         url = 'https://server.com/api?header=' + header ;

      })
      .then(function(){

          request.get({ uri: url }, function (err, resp, body) {

              var resultFromServer = JSON.parse(body);

              return ChangeBuffer(content_type,encoding,body_buffer,resultFromServer);
          });

      })

   }
   ```

In `async` scenarios, using `q` for callbacks is more better than other ways I think.

Comment: are you sure from script above it's proper usage of Q. Doubt about it!

Comment: Yes I totally sure about it. but not best way. Maybe best way is using `Q.all` to be sure about needed data and with `.spread` continue the steps.

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript is asynchronous in nature. Asynchronous is a programming
>   pattern which provides the feature of non-blocking code i.e do not
>   stop or do not depend on another function / process to execute a
>   particular line of code.
>   Ref: [Codementor Article](https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/manage-async-nodejs-callback-example-code)

From Wikipedia

> Node.js provides an event-driven architecture and a non-blocking I/O API designed to optimize an application's throughput and scalability for real-time web applications

What can you do?

1. Use a sleep/wait ie `setTimeout`(Not recommended)
2. Use some async lib like https://github.com/caolan/async (Recommended)
3. Use some promise lib like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)