# Nodejs difference between 'res.json(..)' and 'return res.json(..)'

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I am learning `Nodejs` and I do not fully understand the returns. For example, `next()` in many cases is suggested to be returned in order to make sure execution stop after triggering it ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810449/when-to-use-next-and-return-next-in-node-js)). However, for cases like simple response, is `return` needed, what is the difference and what is preferred:

```
res.json({ message: 'Invalid access token' });
```

vs.

```
return res.json({ message: 'Invalid access token' });
```

Comment: What function is the code above meant to be in? It's impossible to answer the question without that context.

Comment: The code is for simple authentication function that returns response for authentication attempt.

Comment: code below return won't execute :-) Nothing more. I prefer to do not return next() because return statement should be consistent according to [this](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) rule

Comment: @eYe: Show (with specifics), don't tell.

Answer (score 15):

The return is used to stop execution. It is often used to do some form of early return based on a condition.

Forgetting the return often leads to the function continuing execution instead of returning. The examples are typical express middle-ware examples.

If the middle-ware function looks like this:

```
function doSomething(req, res, next){
    return res.json({ message: 'Invalid access token' });
}
```

The resultant behavior would be exactly the same as:

```
function doSomething(req, res, next){
    res.json({ message: 'Invalid access token' });
}
```

But very often this pattern is implemented:

```
function doSomething(req, res, next){
    if(token.isValid){
        return res.json({ message: 'Invalid access token' }); // return is very important here
    }
    next();
}
```

As you can see here when the return is ommited and the token is invlaid, the function will call the res.json() method but then continue on to the next() method which is not the intended behaviour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810449/when-to-use-next-and-return-next-in-node-js?lq=1

Comment: Thank you. So technically if I am careful enough I do not have to return when early return is not required?

Comment: Yes, technically you don`t have to, I try to always return when calling a callback. It just eliminates a lot of debugging time always returning this though. Calling the callbacks more than once it ends in tears. :(

Comment: But why is this the case? If res is sent back to the client, that means, technically, that the HTTP req + res cycle is done and execution is finished. Why isn't res.json() a function terminator on its own.

Comment: @aelmosalamy Technically yes, but we might have interceptors or post-processors. If you are from java world, think about aspect oriented programming etc. So even if response is done, server might want to do some post processing logic like logging or clearing some cache or something. for that reason I think res.json() is not a function terminator on its own.