# can't get Token on frontend for userAuth but everything works fine on my backend as I tested it with insomnia (MERN app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, token, mern

I always get false for isLoggedIn on my fontend but everything is fine on my backend.

backend loginstatus function:

```
const loginStatus = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  if (!token) return res.json(false);

  //Verify Token
  const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  if (verified) return res.json(true);

  return res.json(false);
});
```

on frontend:

```
export const getLoginStatus = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/api/users/loggedin`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.message && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString();
    toast.error(message);
  }
};
```

I tried login from frontend and the backend always sends false as a response for loginStatus

Comment: try read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726863/nodejs-difference-between-res-json-and-return-res-json