# usage of nodejs express next

Tags: node.js, express

I have API to deal with post request as follow(simplified):

```
myFunc(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next){
    let err = 'err detected!';
    //validateSometing() returns a boolean value, true if validation pass false otherwise
    if(!validateSomething()){
       res.status(500).json(err);
       return next(err);
    }  
    //more code...logic if validation pass
}
```

I would like to know if `return next(err);` or `return;` is required to stop the function flow after sending the status and related err back to client. In other words, does `res.status(500).json(err);` stops the function flow?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810449/when-to-use-next-and-return-next-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

`next()` is a middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. You must call `next()` to pass control to the next middleware function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.

**`res.json(), res.send()`** is a express function used to send response to the client  application . In other words it used this functions used to build your HTTP Reponse.

`return` keyword returns from your function, thus ending its execution. This means that any lines of code after it will not be executed.

**Note :** Both `next()` and `res.send()` will not end your function from execution. Where adding a `return` will stop function execution after triggering the callback.

Use `return` is to ensure that the execution stops after triggering the callback. In some circumstances, you may want to use `res.send` and then do other stuff.

**Example :**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is a middleware')
  next()
  console.log('This is first-half middleware')
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is second middleware')
  next()
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is third middleware')
  next()
})
```

Your output will be:

```
This is a middleware
This is second middleware
This is third middleware
This is first-half middleware
```

That is, it runs the code below `next()` after all middleware function finished.

However, if you use `return next()`, it will jump out the callback immediately and the code below `return next()` in the callback will be unreachable.

Comment: next also is used in error handling. ref https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html