# Return type for Express routes with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to use TypeScript to it's full potential, so I avoid `any` if possible.

I've seen Express routes defined like this:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

myRouter.route("/foo").post((req: Request, res: Response): Response => {
  return res.send("Hello World");
});
```

That works because `send()` returns an express `Response`.

But if I do a redirect:

```
myRouter.route("/bar").post((req: Request, res: Response): Response => {
  return res.redirect("/baz");         // redirect() returns void!
});
```

That won't compile because `redirect()` returns void, not `Response`.

Options:

- The easy fix is to make the route return `any`, but I want to avoid that if possible
- I've seen code that does `as unknown as Response` but that seems like a hack

What is the correct way to declare routes' return types, without using `any`?

Comment: Well, Express doesn't pay any attention to the return value so the right way to use it is to define the callback for no return value and to not return a value.  So, stop doing `return res.send()` and just do `res.send()` and `res.redirect()`.  Stop using the `return`.  No `return` is needed if there is no return value and if you're just trying to finish execution of the function, then just use a plain `return;`.  I always disliked the `return res.send()` syntax anyway, even in plain Javascript because it implies a meaningful return value is being returned there when that's not the case.

Comment: @jfriend00 The typings declare a return value... So do you believe it's better to ignore them and declare it as `post(...): void` ?

Comment: No.  You're looking in the wrong place.  This isn't about what `.post()` returns.  It's about what the callback you pass it returns and how the callback is declared to match that.  The callback should return nothing.  All `.post()` does it register the callback so it can be called later and return the object it was called on so things can be chained.  `.post()` itself is called at server initialization time (to register the route handler) - it's not call when the route is actually hit.  The callback that was passed to `.post()` is what's called as the route handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 DOH! You're right! When I created the question I didn't paste my real code - my handlers are in a separate class so they're easier to test, and when I typed the above I looked in the wrong declaration file. You are right - the `RequestHandler` callback is defined as `(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;`... so it returns `any` so I'm happy to do the same. Your comment about not returning unnecessarily was helpful though (what I'd do it other languages).

Comment: @jfriend00 One last point. You say Express doesn't expect routes to return values anyway, so do you ignore the typings (they return `any`) and just declare them to return `void`? I know the typings are a guideline only, but it's good to be consistent. How do you do it?

Comment: I'm not a TypeScript expert so don't have a recommendation there.  I don't like code that returns a value when the return value is not used by the caller (because I think it makes misleading code) so I'd probably do something consistent with that.

Comment: @jfriend00  what do you think of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16811964/857428 `If you don't do it, you risk triggering the callback a second time later, which usually has devastating results.`

Comment: Instead of `return res.redirect(...)` which I find misleading because it appears you're returning some value, I prefer `res.redirect(...);   return;` where I'd put the `return` on a separate line.  Then, it's obvious that the `return` is ONLY about flow control and not returning a value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per @jfriend's comments, the callback's [declaration for RequestHandler](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L35) is:

```
(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
```

So using `any` in this case is okay.

However, declaring it as `void` may be even better as Express doesn't expect a return value. That's what I'm doing, and I'm considering the typings here to be "wrong" (if this isn't the case and there is a valid use case, please let me know).

Comment: `void` is probably the better option, as it's the exact return type

Comment: Looks like they've improved the type for `RequestHandler` since then. As of today, it's `(req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery>, res: Response<ResBody>, next: NextFunction): void;`.