# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client bug with Express and node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I'm stuck with the issue of sending response back to the caller after retrieving something from Postgres database.

It appears that headers are automatically written after `fetchUserDB` is executed (regardless of its success).

This leads to the error `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` when I try to return the response back using `res.json()` menthod.

These are the headers after `fetchUsedDB` is called (just before return statement). Checking `res._headers` you can see that `finished` is set to true after the call is made.

```
access-control-allow-origin:    '*'
content-length:    155
content-security-policy:    'default-src 'none''
content-type:    'text/html; charset=utf-8'
x-content-type-options:    'nosniff'
x-powered-by:    'Express'
```

This is the route managing the endpoint in question:

```
user.get("/detail",async (req,res)=>{
    const {uid} = req.authToken

    fetchUserDB(uid).then(data=>{
        return res.status(200).json({
            data:data[0],
        })
    }).catch(err=>{
        switch (err.name) {
            case 'NoUserWithUid':
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return res.status(404).json({
            error:"user not found"
        })
    })
})
```

The error I'm getting is:

`Uncaught Error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Here is the `fetchUserDB` code:

```
export const fetchUserDB = async (uid)=>{
    client.connect()
    try {
        const query = `SELECT * FROM api.users WHERE firebase_uid = '${uid}'`
        const res = await client.query(query)

        if (res.rows.length == 0) {
            throw new NoUserWithUid(uid)
        }
        return res.rows
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        debugger
    }finally {
        client.end()
    }
}
```

I'm using Express and node-postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 days of struggling I found the solution. In one of my Express API middleware I did use `next()`. What solved the issue was to change it to `return next()`

This caused completely unexpected behaviour with axios and async/await.

[When to use next() and return next() in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810449/when-to-use-next-and-return-next-in-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

why don't you simplify your code as bellow

```
user.get("/detail", async (req, res) => {
const {
    uid
} = req.authToken

try {
    const user = await fetchUserDB(uid)
    return res.status(200).json({
        data: data[0],
    })
} catch (err) {
    switch (err.name) {
        case 'NoUserWithUid':
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return res.status(404).json({
        error: "user not found"
    })
}
```

})